# Passing data between ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

To pass in values to the other fragment I have on my ViewPager I am doing the following:

**FragmentA.java**

```
//Initial Declaration
ListPasser handler;


public interface ListPasser{
    public void onPodCastClick(int position, String url, String title, String body, String date);
}


//I am implementing a ListView inside the fragment
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.i(tag, mp3URL);
    Log.i(tag, String.valueOf(position));
    Log.i(tag, pod_title);
    Log.i(tag, pod_body);
    Log.i(tag, pod_date);
    handler.onPodCastClick(position, mp3URL, pod_title, pod_body, pod_date);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        handler = (ListPasser) getActivity();

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.i(tag,"Activity " + getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName()
            + " does not implement the ElemetsListClickHandler interface");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java (Implementing class for the ViewPager)**

```
@Override
public void onPodCastClick(int position, String url, String title,
        String body, String date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle element = new Bundle();
    element.putInt("position", position);
    element.putString("mp3url", url);
    element.putString("title", title);
    element.putString("body", body);
    element.putString("date", date);

    Fragment toGo = new FragmentB();
    toGo.setArguments(element);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.pager, toGo);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
TextView npTitle, npDate, npDescription;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.now_playing_layout, container, false);


    npTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.npTitle);
    npDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.npDate);
    npDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.npDescription);

    Bundle element = this.getArguments();
    if(element != null){
    String title = element.getString("title");
    String url = element.getString("mp3url");
    String body = element.getString("body");

    npTitle.setText(title);
    npDescription.setText(body);
    }
    else{
        npTitle.setText("Its null man");
        npDescription.setText("NULL POINTER EXCEPTION !");
    }
    return view;
}
```

When I click an item in `FragmentA` it is to go to `FragmentB` carrying with it information as show in the interface but all this is giving me is a blank screen on `FragmentA`. Please do help.

Comment: The code looks OK. What line are you getting the NullPointerException exactly?

Comment: @GaneshBhambarkar its not actually a NullPointerException ... FragmentA goes blank on click. And when I try to go to FragmentB, thats where I get the NullPointerException on the line `Bundle element = this.getArguments()`

Comment: Try to get the `Bundle` values in context of `getActivity.getArguments()` in your FragmentB

Comment: @GrIsHu it doesnt work

Comment: Do you get any kind of error ? Are all the values printed in your logcat in your onItemClick ?

Comment: @GrIsHu no error, i just get a blank activity. All my log entries return the values. I was getting a NullPointerException on FragmentB earlier.

Comment: Can you post some more code of `FragmentB` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use abstract class to hold the values in an Object. Then use a static method to get the value from any other class.

Comment: something similar to `SharedPrefernces` ?

Comment: Yes you can see it as a container class. Static means that's its always the same so you can call the static method on the class name. with not need for creating an object of that class